# Clean Url not enabling

Tags: uri

I have problem in clean url i am trying to enable it but it showing radio buttons deactivated and showing Your system configuration does not currently support this feature.[image]

My web is on shared hosting under the sub directory Like This
http://tailoredsuitonline.com.previewdns.com/oceanwis/ The main Web is "Oceanwis"

Your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if mod_rewrite is enabled (if you are using Apache as your web server).
2. Add .htaccess file to the root of Drupal installation. Here is [a link to documentation.](https://drupal.org/node/15365)